# Strange result of sorting in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have got a very strange result trying to sort an array:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].sort(function(a,b) {return a > b;})
```

Result:

```
[5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I would like to understand, why is this result return? 
I know, that sort function should be written like this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].sort(function(a,b) {return a - b;})
```

Comment: works fine for me

Comment: The result is probably implementation dependant.

Comment: @LelioFaieta It's not that it doesn't work, it's that the OP wants to know why `a > b` results in `5` being at the start.

Comment: Read the documentation for `Array#sort`. You might as well ask what the result of `.sort(() => Math.random - 0.5)` was.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort Does not expect a Boolean

Comment: @JamesThorpe my comment was to say that I cannot reproduce the issue. The sort works fine with both codes on my machine

Comment: I'm not sure _why_ it messes up, but you can expand the `a>b` to return only 0 or 1, no -1, and get the same results. `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].sort(function(a,b) {return (a-b) > 0 ? 1 : 0;})`

Comment: your first sort function is not kind of symetrical in the way as it should be: `sortFn(a, b) === -sortFn(b, a)`, because you get only values of `0` and `1` (the numerical value).

Comment: Why is the first result strange? Your sort comparator doesn't return what it is supposed to, and so the fact that the result isn't properly sorted is not a surprise. `.sort(function() { return "hello" })` doesn't sort properly either, but so what?

Comment: I suppose, that deep understanding of how javascript sort method works isn't a bad thing. I just want to understand, which sorting algorithms is applied and how they work. For arrays with up to 10 numbers, bubble sort is applied, if I understood correctly. If we use `.sort(function() { return "hello" })` we will get `[5, 10, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 1, 4, 3, 2]`, because `return "hello"` == `return true` == `return 1`. May be I am wrong.

Comment: useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559608/median-of-three-values-strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could get strange sorting results, for example in Chrome, where the sorting starts with the first and last element and goes on with the middle element.

Basicall you get the following protocoll

> ```
>                   return  needed
>   a    b   a > b   value   value  comment
> ---  ---  ------  ------  ------  -----------
>   0   10   false       0      -1  wrong value
>   0    5   false       0      -1  wrong value
>   2    0    true       1       1
>   9    0    true       1       1
>   8    0    true       1       1
>   7    0    true       1       1
>   6    0    true       1       1
>   1    0    true       1       1
>   4    0    true       1       1
>   3    0    true       1       1
>   2    3   false       0      -1  wrong value
>   3    4   false       0      -1  wrong value
>   4    1    true       1       1
>   3    1    true       1       1
>   2    1    true       1       1
>   4    6   false       0      -1  wrong value
>   6    7   false       0      -1  wrong value
>   7    8   false       0      -1  wrong value
>   8    9   false       0      -1  wrong value
>   9   10   false       0      -1  wrong value
> ```

Basically you get a value for equal items, bu you have unequal items to compare.

You need a stable sort function which is kind of symetrical in the way as it yields the nevgative value with switched parameters.

```
sortFn(a, b) === -sortFn(b, a)
```

If you return only values of `0` and `1`, you miss `-1`.

```js
console.log([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].sort(function(a, b) {
    console.log(a, b, a > b);
    return a > b;
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```