# Your function partition_median () does not use the median of the first middle and last element, but only takes the middle element

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, median

need to correct this i want to use quick sort median pivot emelent
my professor is asking me this statement

Your function partition_median () does not use the median of the first middle and last element, but only takes the middle element.

but i do no know

```
def partition_median(req_list,start_index,end_index):
    """Function get Pivot at meadian."""
    pivot = req_list[(end_index+start_index)//2]
    i, j = start_index - 1, end_index + 1
    while True:
        i += 1
        j -= 1
        while req_list[i] < pivot:
            i += 1
        while req_list[j] > pivot:
            j -= 1

        if i >= j:
            return j

        req_list[i], req_list[j] = req_list[j], req_list[i]
def qsort_median(req_list, start_index, end_index):
    """Function to sort by median."""
    if start_index < end_index:
        pivot = partition_median(req_list, start_index, end_index)
        qsort_median(req_list, start_index, pivot)
        qsort_median(req_list, pivot + 1, end_index)


def quicksort_pivot_median(list_re):
    """Function sorting by median."""
    qsort_median(list_re, 0, len(list_re) - 1)
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what you “do no know”. Do you understand the concept of a median? Do you understand the difference between an index and the value stored at that index? Do you understand that the value in the middle of a list is only guaranteed to be the median if the list is already sorted?

Comment: This  [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7560859/3282056) explains for quicksort median of 3,  it is better to actually sort the first, middle, and last elements in each partition step, to improve performance for the later recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as your teacher is saying, you are taking the middle element as pivot:

```
pivot = req_list[(end_index+start_index)//2]
```

Apparently you were asked to *"use the median of the first, middle and last element"*. So at least you need to *inspect* those three values:

```
a = req_list[start_index]
b = req_list[(end_index+start_index)//2]
c = req_list[end_index]
# The median of 3 values can be got by taking them all, 
#    but then subtracting the two extremes from it:
pivot = a + b + c - max(a, b, c) - min(a, b, c)
```

See also Wikipedia on [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median).

Comment: I deleted my prior comments, as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7560859/3282056), it is better to actually sort the first, middle, and last values, for the following recursive calls. For pseudo-random data, it is only slightly faster. I tested an array of 16 million pseudo-random integers using a C++ Hoare partition quicksort, and sorting first, middle, last is only 1% to 2% faster.